# If I flip four coins, what is the probability that the first coin is heads AND there are more heads than tails?

Tags: probability

I don't know why this answer is eluding me, but I had to figure it out somehow. I know that the probability of flipping heads first is 1/2. 8/16 outcomes have H first. The probability of having more heads than tails is 5/16: HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HTHH, THHH. I realize that I can count it and that four of these results have H first, meaning that the answer is 4/16 or 1/4. However, how is this calculated mathematically? You can not simply multiply the two probabilities as they are inclusive. I know that they are independent as well. The first coin flip doesn't matter to having more heads than tails as it is still possible regardless. What probability formula would I need to solve this?

Comment: Do *not* confuse the word "dependent" with "mutually exclusive."  You say "*I know that they are independent as well.  The first coin flip doesn't matter to having more heads than tails as it is still possible regardless.*"  That is incorrect thinking.  It still being possible regardless implies that they have nontrivial intersection implying they are not mutually exclusive.  Independence is an entirely different concept unrelated to mutual exclusivity.

Comment: "*How is this calculated mathematically?*"  Exactly like you did.  $\frac{4}{16}$ is exactly right.  Otherwise, you could phrase the calculation as $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$.  Letting $A$ be the event that there is a head on the first flip and $B$ the event that there are more heads than tails, you see $\Pr(B\mid A)$ corresponds to there being two or three heads in the final three flips and can be calculated via binomial distribution as $(3+1)\cdot \frac{1}{2^3}$ giving the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing "un-mathematical" about your approach; it is perfectly fine.

Another approach is to realize that after the first flip is heads, you need at least 2 heads in the last 3 flips, which has probability $4/8=1/2$. So,
\begin{align}
&P(\text{first flip is heads, more heads than tails in 4 flips})
\\
&= P(\text{first flip is heads}) P(\text{more heads than tails in 4 flips} \mid \text{first flip is heads})
\\
&= P(\text{first flip is heads}) P(\text{at least two heads in the last 3 flips})
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you cannot multiply the probabilities. However this is because the events are **not** independent.

The outcomes for obtaining heads first and more heads are: $\sf\{HHHH, HHHT,HHTH,HTHH\}$, which are four from the sixteen total outcomes. (Thus the answer is $1/4$).

The outcomes for obtaining *tails* first and more heads are: $\sf\{THHH\}$, which is one from the sixteen total outcomes.

Thus there is a dependency between the event of "the first is a head" and "there are more heads than tails."

---

You seek the probability that you have obtained a head first, *and* two or three heads among the remaining three. That is expressing the favored event as an intersection of independent events, so...$$\dfrac 12\cdot\left(\binom 32+1\right)\dfrac 1{2^3}=\dfrac 14$$